# Continue reading file from the position where it was left

Tags: python

I have to read a file multiple times in which some error info is appended everyday. Is there a way to start reading the file from the point it was left previous day instead of start reading from beginning again? I don't have permission to write in file. so marking the end is out of option. One possible way i got is to store the cursor position and then seek to that position next time.. Is there any other way through python?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the python `tell` file method to see what position you are in a file before you close it and the `seek` method to return to that position after you open it again.

---

Example:

Given a file `foo` with the contents

```
edas
agfa
agf
fgfgfg
```

You can return to a given position as follows:

```
>>> f = open('foo')
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.readline()
'edas\n'
>>> f.tell()
5
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('foo')
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.seek(5)
>>> f.readline()
'agfa\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - it's possible. I believe - you've a file whose size is pretty big enough that you don't want to read from start every time. So here's something you can do - write to a file in your home directory `.fileinfo`  or something and in that write the last offset of the file you read in that file. And then your program can do something like following

```
if not os.path.exists('/home/.fileinfo'):
     seek_from = 0
else:
     of = open('/home/.fileinfo', 'r')
     seek_from = int(of.readline().strip())

with open('/path/to/your/file', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(seek_from, 0)

    # do whatever you want
    f.seek(0,-1) # Go to the end of the file
    end = f.tell() # Get the position
    of = open('/home/.fileinfo', 'w')
    of.write(str(end))
    of.close()
```

Something along these lines.

Hope that helps

Comment: As per ask, he do not have access to write to file. So this will not help him much